# Add tocline depending on string compare

Tags: table-of-contents, comparison, ifthenelse

### !! Attention !!

Because this topic developed some amount of complexity, I tried to restructure the topic considering the newly gathered information.
Please see this post to find the latest detail: [Override macro with \renewcommand{} multiple times from different files - toc addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454637/override-macro-with-renewcommand-multiple-times-from-different-files-toc-ad)

---

I would like to add a line to my toc, depending on the comparison of two strings.

### Inital setup

In the root-file I defined two commands

```
\newcommand{\Field}{Dummyfield}
\newcommand{\OldField}{}
```

The root-file gets a lot of chapter-files to read from. 
Every chapter redefines the `\Field{}`-command.
What I want to do is to compare the strings in `Field{}` and `\OldField{}` and if they are not equal, I want to add a line to the toc, saying whatever `\Field{}` holds.

My files are:
**(Root-file)**

```
% Dokument-Grundeinstellungen
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage, parskip=half]{scrbook}
%   \usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % Format und Seitenraender
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}                                                   % Zeilenabstand
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Schriftart
%\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}                    % Helvetica (skaliert) als serifenlose Schriftart (Standard fuer serifenlose Schrift)  -- besser geeigent zum Lesen am BILDSCHIRM
    % \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}     % (Eingestellte) serifenlose Schrift als Standardschrftart (fuer Fliesstext)
\usepackage{lmodern}                                % Besser lesbare Standardschriftart (Serifenschrift) -- besser geeigent zum Lesen auf PAPIER
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}       % (Eingestellte) Serifenschriftart als Standardschrift (fuer Fliesstext)
    \setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}    % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (fett)
    %\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}            % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (plain)
\usepackage{color}                                  % Textfarbe aendern - Fuer Dokument, Paragraph oder diskrete Texteile mit '\textcolor{Farbe}{Text}'



%------------------------------------------------------------

% Kopf- und Fusszeile
\usepackage[markcase=noupper, headsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % no uppercasing
        \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
        \setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
        \setlength{\footheight}{2cm}
        \newcommand{\Field}{Dummyfield}
        \newcommand{\OldField}{}
    \ihead{Name: Jon Doe\\ Ausbildungsbereich: \Field}
    \ohead{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm]{./Bilder/Logo.jpg}}
    %\cfoot{\pagemark}

%------------------------------------------------------------

% Ausgabe von Umlauten (vor 'inputenc' einbinden!)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Schoene Ausgabe von Umlauten
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute direkt eingeben   UTF-8 zur besseren Zusammenarbeit mit vers. Betriebssystemen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Eingabe (Zur Eingabe von Umlauten wird 'inputenc' benötigt)
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Mathematik-Bibliotheken
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Schoene Formelumgebung - align{, \[ \], ... - NICHT eqnarray, displaymath 
\usepackage{amssymb}    % mathematische Schriftarten, Zeichensaetze und Symbole - laedt automatisch das Paket 'asmfonts'
\usepackage{mathptmx}   % Funktion aktuell Unklar. Vmt: Verbindung von drei Schriftarten fuer serifen, serifenlosund typewriter Fonts: Times/Helvetica/Courier (Helvetica akaliert - siehe Schriftart)
    \usepackage{courier} % Schritart Courier als Typewriter-Font einstellen
\usepackage[exponent-product = \cdot, decimalsymbol=comma, per=frac ]{siunitx}  % SI-Einheiten verwenden Bsp: \SI{100}{\degreeCelsius}
\usepackage{advdate}                                    % Datumberechnungen anstellen
    \newcommand{\Datum}{00/00/0000}     % Leeres Datum vorbelegen
\usepackage{ifthen}
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Weitere Zeichensaetze
\usepackage{textcomp}   % Erweiterter Zeichensatz
\usepackage{enumitem}   % spez. Nummerierungen z.B. a) b) c)
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Bilder, Grafiken und Dokumente einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Bilder und Grafiken einbinden '\includegraphics[Optionen]{Herkunft/Speicherort}'
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % umfliessende Grafiken '\begin{wrapfigure}{Position{Breite} ..'
\usepackage{here}       % Figures (Bilder) genau an dieser Stelle einbinden / Einbinden erzwingen - Option [H] - !!ACHTUNG!! Als Option fuer Gleitumgebungen gedacht, widerspricht aber dem Sinn einer Gleitumgebung !
\usepackage{pdfpages}   % PDF-Dokumente einbinden
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % Objektgroessen anpassen/skalieren
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    \usepackage{pgffor}     
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Referenzen/Links lauffaehig machen
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}       % Unmittelbares Erzeugen von PDF-Ausgabe / Verknuefpungen/Links herstellen UND Ermoeglichung von urls: \url{}
\usepackage{cleveref}               % Erweiterte Refernzenbefehle -- IMMER NACH hyperref lade
    \crefname{enumi}{Punkt}{Punkte} % Aendert den angezeigten Namen des Labels 'enumi' in 'Punkt' bzw. 'Punkte' (Plural)
    \crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
    \crefname{eqation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \Crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \crefname{subsection}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
    %\Crefname{subsection}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}      % Noeatig um cref-Namen neu zu besetzen
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}


% Dauer-Kommando 
\newcommand{\dauer}[1]{\SI{#1}{\hour}}
% Kalendarwochen-Kommando
\newcommand{\KW}{00}
% Tabellenfarbe definier
\definecolor{tabcol}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}


\begin{document}
 %------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents                % Inhaltverzeichnis erzeugen
\newpage
%-----------------------------------------------------------
    %\cleardoublepage
    %\cleardoublepage   
    \include{./2018/2018}
            \foreach \i in {00, 01, 02, ..., 99}{%
    \edef\FileName{./2018/Wochen/KW\i}%
    \IfFileExists{\FileName}{%
        \include{\FileName}%
    }
}
\end{document}
```

And one of the **content-file**s (part of):

```
% ----------------------------------------EINSTELLUNGEN--------------------------------------------------
% ---------------------------- ANFANGSTAG  UND KW SETZEN ----------------------------------------
                                    \renewcommand{\Datum}{00/00/0000}                           % Datumsvariable neu setzen {TT/MM/JJJJ}
                                    \renewcommand{\KW}{36}                                                  % KW neu setzen; z.B. {36} fuer KW 136
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\SetDate[\Datum]%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      % \today per advdate aendern
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ------------------------------------ BEREICH SETZEN ---------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\OldField}{\Field}% ------------------- Vorherigen bereich speichern ------
                            \renewcommand{\Field}{Testfield I}                              % Neuen Bereich setzen                  
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{KW \KW{} \hspace{12pt}\today{} - \AdvanceDate[4]\today}%---------------
\ifthenelse{ \not\equal{\OldField}{\Field}  }{%
    \addtocounter{section}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\Field}}{
}
%  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\SetDate[\Datum] %-- Datum zurücksetzen auf Wochenanfang-----------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%
```

I hope anyone can help me with this.
Regards

### After Werner's idea

Considering @Werner's answer, I changed my code.
But I think there is still some kind of problem with my understanding of the mechanics.
Below my new try for a **content-file**:

```
\let\OldField\Field% ------------------- Vorherigen Bereich speichern ----------------------
% ------------------------------------ BEREICH SETZEN ---------------------------------------------------
                            \renewcommand{\Field}{Service Desk}                                 % <--- Neuen Bereich setzen                 
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{KW \KW{} \hspace{12pt}\today{} - \AdvanceDate[4]\today}%----------------
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\Field}{\OldField}=0
\else
    \addtocounter{section}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\Field}%------------------------------------------------------
\fi
```

But it still adds a new toc-entry for every file I include, no matter if the Fileds differ or not.

---

### **Values of** `\Field` **and** `\OldField` **at different points in the code**

I let the .log-file show me all the values of `\Field` and `\OldFiled` at different points in my code and over the (currently) two files the root-file can read from.

```
\show\OldField %respectively \show\Field
\let\OldField\Field% ------------------- Vorherigen Bereich speichern ----------------------
%\show\OldField %respectively \show\Field
% ------------------------------------ BEREICH SETZEN ---------------------------------------------------
                            \renewcommand{\Field}{Service Desk}                                 % <--- Neuen Bereich setzen                 
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\show\OldField %respectively \show\Field
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{KW \KW{} \hspace{12pt}\today{} - \AdvanceDate[4]\today}%----------------
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\Field}{\OldField}=0
\else
    \addtocounter{section}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\Field}%------------------------------------------------------
\fi
```

**These are the values**
[image: Values at the three points]

So for me it seems like the values of `\OldField` is always taken from the initial `newcommand{\OldField}{Dummyfield}` in the root-file.
And that's pretty bad.
Now it makes perfect sense, that the `strcmp` never 0 and therefore running the `else-statement`. 
The question however is, *Why does \OldField (always) show its initial value from the commands definition?* And ever more important: Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying `\Field` into `\OldField` using

```
\renewcommand{\OldField}{\Field}
```

doesn't achieve what you want since the content of `\Field` is not expanded upon (re)definition of `\OldField`. Instead, `\OldField` is defined to be the same as `\Field`, which you change in a subsequent definition. As such, `\OldField` will always be the same as `\Field` and you'll never pick up a change.

Instead, you can copy the entire definition of `\Field` into `\OldField` using

```
\let\OldField\Field
```

and then perform conditioning using `\ifx` or a `pdf` `str`ing `c`o`mp`arison:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% \Field and \OldField are the same
\newcommand{\OldField}{One}
\newcommand{\Field}{One}

\ifx\Field\OldField
  \verb|\Field| = \verb|\OldField| = \Field
\else
  \verb|\Field| = \Field; \verb|\OldField| = \OldField
\fi

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\Field}{\OldField}=0
  \verb|\Field| = \verb|\OldField| = \Field
\else
  \verb|\Field| = \Field; \verb|\OldField| = \OldField
\fi

\bigskip

% \Field and \OldField are different
\let\OldField\Field % Copy \Field into \OldField
\renewcommand{\Field}{Two}

\ifx\Field\OldField
  \verb|\Field| = \verb|\OldField| = \Field
\else
  \verb|\Field| = \Field; \verb|\OldField| = \OldField
\fi

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\Field}{\OldField}=0
  \verb|\Field| = \verb|\OldField| = \Field
\else
  \verb|\Field| = \Field; \verb|\OldField| = \OldField
\fi

\end{document}
```

`\ifx<cmdA><cmdB>` checks whether the *definition* of `<cmdA>` matches that of `<cmdB>`, while `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}` checks whether the (expanded) *text* `<strA>` matches `<strB>`, returning 0 if that's the case. This allows one to check it with `\ifnum<pdfstrmp>=0`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this very elaborated example.
I tried to implement it. 
Please see my edited post above.
Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: Did you compile twice? Entries in the ToC need (at least) 2 compilations to settle.

Comment: Yes, compiled like a thousend times in a row for I know this behavior.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: What does `\show\Field` and `\show\OldField` look like just before your test? Based on what you're saying, they should always be different. Is that the case? Can you provide a minimal example that I can use to replicate your current (problematic) behaviour?

Comment: BEFORE I redefine the `\Field` in `\renewcommand{\Field}{Testfield I}` (but after `\let\OldField\Field`) they show this: `\Field=\long macro:
->DummyField.
l.10 \show\Field` (which is my default)

`\OldField=\long macro:
->Dummyfield.
l.10 \show\OldField`


AFTER I redefine `\Field` the .log shows:
`\Field=\long macro:
->Testfield I.
l.13 \show\Field`

`\OldField=\long macro:
->Dummyfield.
l.13 \show\OldField
`

Comment: I just figured out what might be the problem. Please see my latest edit above

Comment: To have a better structure, I opened a new topic revolving around the (as-it-seems) real problem here. 
Please check the start of my initial post to find the link to the new topic. 
I'd love to find you @Werner there

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: The only way the definitions will remain the same is if they are being set within a group somehow. This seems to be the case with your use of `\foreach`. Try with `\global\let\OldField\Field`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `\OldField` macro will always expand to `\Field`, so the test will return true.

You need

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\OldField\expandafter{\Field}
```

so `\OldField` will expand to the current contents of `\Field`, that you redefine later on.

A simpler method, once you get the hang of it, is

```
\let\OldField\Field
```